# incomplete types with std::map and std::variant

Tags: c++, c++17, libstdc++, incomplete-type

Consider this simplified and very specific implementation of a recursive variant on top of `std::variant`:

```
#include <map>
#include <variant>

struct recursive_tag;

template <typename...>
struct RecursiveVariant;

template <>
struct RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag>>
    : std::variant<int, std::map<int, RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag>>>>
{
    using underlying = std::variant<int,
          std::map<int, RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag>>>>;
    using underlying::underlying;
};


int main() {
    RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag>> rv; 
}
```

This fails to compile on gcc 7/8 due to trying to instantiate `std::pair<const int, recursive_tag>`, which itself fails because `recursive_tag` is an incomplete type.

But, nothing in the compiler error call-stack indicates to me *why* `std::pair<const int, recursive_tag>` needs to be instantiated. The top line there is:

> variant:252:48:   required from ‘`void std::__detail::__variant::__erased_dtor(_Variant&&) [with _Variant = const std::__detail::__variant::_Variant_storage<false, int, std::map<int, RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, recursive_tag> > > >, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, RecursiveVariant<int, std::map<int, recursive_tag, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<const int, recursive_tag> > > > > > > >&; long unsigned int _Np = 0]`’

pointing to:

```
249   template<typename _Variant, size_t _Np>
250     void
251     __erased_dtor(_Variant&& __v)
252     { std::_Destroy(std::__addressof(__get<_Np>(__v))); }
```

While type `map<int, recursive_tag>` is spelled in there, the actual `map` type that should be instantiated is `map<int, RecursiveVariant<int, map<int, recursive_tag>>>`... which should only necessitate the instantiation of `pair<const int, RecursiveVariant<...>>`.

Simply making `recursive_tag` complete (i.e. by adding `{}`) fixes the problem. But what causes the problem to begin with?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The [line at issue](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/8bc5c186d9e5d83cdf9619483e60294ffb7bf630/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/std/variant#L252) calls

```
std::_Destroy(std::__addressof(__get<_Np>(__v)));
```

The need to perform ADL for `__get` is sufficient to trigger instantiation of any and all associated classes of the type of `__v`, i.e., `_Variant`, to look for potential friend functions (and function templates) with that name defined within these classes. That includes the `pair` that tripped you up.

Comment: Argh, how are there still more unqualified calls to that function in that file. I'm sure new ones appear overnight.