# Variadic template only compiles when forward declared

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17, variadic-templates, forward-declaration

I have a variadic template that inherits from all template arguments:

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct derived : Ts...
{
};
```

I would also like to have a facility for expressing the type of "existing `derived` with added template arguments". My attempt at this is:

```
// Do not ODR-use (goes in namespace impl or similar)!
template<class ... NewInputs, class ... ExistingInputs>
auto addedHelper(const derived<ExistingInputs...>&)
    -> derived<ExistingInputs..., NewInputs...>;

template<class ExistingInput, class ... NewInputs>
using Added = decltype(addedHelper<NewInputs...>(std::declval<ExistingInput>()));
```

As a simple example, `Added<derived<A, B>, C>` should be `derived<A, B, C>`. I use the helper function for template argument deduction of the first parameter pack.

My problem: For some reason, I can use this successfully with incomplete types if `derived` has been forward declared, but **not** if it was defined.

**Why does this code [not compile](https://godbolt.org/z/ePhquh):**

```
#include <utility>

template <typename... Ts>
struct derived : Ts...
{};

template<class ... NewInputs, class ... ExistingInputs>
auto addedHelper(const derived<ExistingInputs...>&)
    -> derived<ExistingInputs..., NewInputs...>;

template<class ExistingInput, class ... NewInputs>
using Added = decltype(addedHelper<NewInputs...>(std::declval<ExistingInput>()));


struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

// Goal: This forward declaration should work (with incomplete A, B, C).
auto test(derived<A, B> in) -> Added<decltype(in), C>;


struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

void foo()
{
    auto abc = test({});

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(abc), derived<A, B, C>>, "Pass");
}
```

**Whereas this code [does compile](https://godbolt.org/z/qow3Kb):**

```
#include <utility>

template <typename... Ts>
struct derived;


template<class ... NewInputs, class ... ExistingInputs>
auto addedHelper(const derived<ExistingInputs...>&)
    -> derived<ExistingInputs..., NewInputs...>;

template<class ExistingInput, class ... NewInputs>
using Added = decltype(addedHelper<NewInputs...>(std::declval<ExistingInput>()));


struct A;
struct B;
struct C;

// Goal: This forward declaration should work (with incomplete A, B, C).
auto test(derived<A, B> in) -> Added<decltype(in), C>;


template <typename... Ts>
struct derived : Ts...
{};


struct A {};
struct B {};
struct C {};

void foo()
{
    auto abc = test({});

    static_assert(std::is_same_v<decltype(abc), derived<A, B, C>>, "Pass");
}
```

For convenience, here are both cases at once (comment in/out `#define FORWARD_DECLARED`): https://godbolt.org/z/7gM52j

I do not understand how code could possibly become illegal by replacing a forward declaration by the respective definition (which would otherwise just come later).

Comment: Observation: GCC accepts the code if you add `::`: `using Added = decltype(::addedHelper...`.

Comment: @Evg Ok what the hell... ADL rears its ugly head once again.

Comment: I think it is unspecified if instantiation in un-evaluated context might happens.

Comment: You might run into ODR violations here...

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Where exactly?

Comment: @MaxLanghof before and after `derived` has a body.  Calling `test`.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Do you mean that `derived<A, B>` is ODR-used in the `test` forward declaration? Good point, I'm only using references to `derived` originally though, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Evg's observation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56702968/variadic-template-only-compiles-when-forward-declared#comment99970528_56702968) hits the nail on the head: the problem here is ADL. It's actually the same problem I ran into [with this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50589231/2069064).

The issue is this: we have an unqualified call here:

```
template<class ExistingInput, class ... NewInputs>
using Added = decltype(addedHelper<NewInputs...>(std::declval<ExistingInput>()));
//                     ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

We know it's a function template because we find it in using regular lookup, so we don't have to deal with the whole "is `<` an operator or a template introducer" question. However, because it's an unqualified call, we *also* must perform argument-dependent lookup.

ADL needs to look into the associated namespaces of all the arguments, which seems fine - we don't need complete types for that. But ADL *also* needs to look for potential friend functions and function templates defined within the classes. After all, this needs to work:

```
struct X {
    friend void foo(X) { }
};
foo(X{}); // must work, call the hidden friend defined within X
```

As a result, in our call in question:

```
auto test(derived<A, B> in) -> Added<decltype(in), C>;
```

We have to instantiate `derived<A, B>`... but that type inherits from two incomplete classes, which we can't do. That's where the problem is, that's where we fail.

This is why the forward declaration version works. `template <typename... T> struct derived;` is incomplete, so just trying to look inside of it for friend functions trivially finds nothing - we don't need to instantiate anything else.

Likewise, a version where `derived` was complete but didn't actually derive from anything would also work.

---

Thankfully, this is fixable in this context with what Evg suggested. Make a qualified call:

```
template<class ExistingInput, class ... NewInputs>
using Added = decltype(::addedHelper<NewInputs...>(std::declval<ExistingInput>()));
```

This avoids ADL, which you didn't even want. Best case, you're avoiding doing something that has no benefit to you. Bad case, your code doesn't compile. Evil case, for some inputs you accidentally call a different function entirely.

---

Or just use Boost.Mp11's [`mp_push_back`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/mp11/doc/html/mp11.html#mp_push_backl_t)

Comment: But Clang reject the code even with `::`. That's why I mentioned GCC explicitly.

Comment: @Oliv, did you miss `friend` there?

Comment: @Evg Indeed! Related question: is [this code](https://godbolt.org/z/tlaLzm) ill-formed?

Comment: @Oliv note that your question does not seem to involve ADL.

Comment: So the snippet with forward declaration is also incorrect (even if it compiles)?

Comment: @Oliv No it's not, and I fixed my answer -- right general idea, but had the wrong specifics before.

Comment: Note that the ADL lookup that `so just trying to look inside of it for friend functions trivially finds nothing` could lead to ODR violations I expect; a lookup where the template *is* complete and so are the base types would lead to a different result from it.  And that is usually ODR-toxic.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah such things are ill-formed, NDR.

Comment: Good catch on the ADL part; I just want to mention why Clang rejects the code even with `::`: [\[temp.deduct.call\]/4](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call#4). Clang is arguably right: the wording seems to say (in the next paragraph) that those alternatives are all-or-nothing; whether that makes sense in cases such as this one is another question... Solution: `addedHelper(derived<ExistingInputs...>&&)`, to avoid the alternatives altogether. cc @Evg

Comment: I ended up going with the template specialization approach that Boost.MP uses. That also feels cleaner than using a function without definition...